# ¿Cómo puedo convertir muchos ficheros con ffmpeg manteniendo el nombre y cambiando solamente la extensión?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

Necesito pasar unos 50 vídeos webm a mp4.

No sé mucho de bash, pero la idea es que se queden con el mismo nombre que tenían antes de cambiar de formato:

```sh
ffmpeg -i *.webm ?.mp4
```

`?` es donde no sé qué poner para que los deje con el mismo nombre.

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿están todas en el mismo directorio? ¿hay otros ficheros que no quieras convertir o todos ellos se deben convertir?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49092444/1983854

Comment: Están todos en el mismo directorio, para convertir todo.

Answer (score 3):

Utiliza el hecho que `${variable%X}` elimina la parte "X" del final de una cadena:

```
$ d="hola.mp4"
$ echo "${d%.mp4}"
hola
$ d="hola.mp4.mp4.bla.mp4"
$ echo "${d%.mp4}"
hola.mp4.mp4.bla
```

Por tanto, solamente debes iterar sobre todos los ficheros cuyo nombre termina por ".webm" dentro del directorio "/algun/directorio/" y realizar el cambio uno a uno:

```
for fichero in /algun/directorio/*.webm
do
    ffmpeg -i "$fichero" "${fichero%.webm}".mp4
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes unos pocos archivos con los que quieras experimentar, podrías hacerlo con esto:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.webm" \
| grep -Po '.*(?=webm$)' \
| xargs -I % bash -c 'ffmpeg -i %{webm,mp4}'
```

Lo que hago aquí es listar con `find` los archivos con extensión `webm`, luego, con `grep -Po` "elimino" la extensión (en realidad sólo elijo lo que esté antes de la extensión, incluyendo el punto) para tener únicamente su nombre con el punto. Luego paso estos nombres como parámetro a xargs que los va a sustituir con el caracter `%` en el comando que se le ingrese.

Por ejemplo, si tienes un directorio con los siguientes archivos.

```
 % find .
.
./archivo1.webm
./archivo10.webm
./archivo2.webm
./archivo3.webm
./archivo4.webm
./archivo5.webm
./archivo6.webm
./archivo7.webm
./archivo8.webm
./archivo9.webm
```

Con `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.webm" | grep -Po '.*(?=webm$)'` obtienes:

```
./archivo1. 
./archivo10.
./archivo2. 
...
```

Y con:

```
% find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.webm" \
  | grep -Po '.*(?=webm$)' \
  | xargs -I % bash -c 'echo %{webm,mp4}'
```

Obtienes:

```
./archivo1.webm ./archivo1.mp4
./archivo10.webm ./archivo10.mp4
./archivo2.webm ./archivo2.mp4
./archivo3.webm ./archivo3.mp4
...
```

En el último ejemplo uso solamente `echo %{webm,mp4}` para mostrar como funciona la expansión. En la cual el nombre del archivo (además del punto) ingresado por `grep` se v a expander de `archivo.{webm,mp4}` como `archivo.webm archivo.mp4`, ya que el nombre del archivo se sustituirá por el token `%` que se le añadió seguido del parámetro `-I` de `xargs`.

Ahora que si te animaste y lo quieres rápido, puedes añadirle a `xargs` más procesos con el parámetro `-P <número de procesos en paralelo>`. En un ejemplo completo podría ser.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.webm" \
| grep -Po '.*(?=webm$)' \
| xargs -P0 -I % bash -c 'ffmpeg -i %{webm,mp4}'
```

Donde 0 denota el máximo de procesos posibles.